# Sendkeys will not run in middle of macro

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I am attempting to use VBA to automate the pulling of data from Hyperion (I am new to VBA).  I have to select a cell range on Sheet 1, "press" Alt,X,S,R, allow it to pull the data, then go to the next sheet and repeat.  The problem I am experiencing is that the macro runs through the tabs and highlights the cells as necessary, however the sendkeys (all five instances) run at the end of the full macro rather than after each step.  Any help would be appreciated.  Macro 1-5 are the exact same with different sheet names.

Code I currently have:

```
Sub RunAllMacros()
Macro1
Macro2
Macro3
Macro4
Macro5
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Range("C5:H15").Select
    Range("H15").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1:H15").Select
    Range("H15").Activate
    SendKeys ("%"), True
    SendKeys ("x"), True
    SendKeys ("s"), True
    SendKeys ("r"), True
    Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

End Sub
```

Comment: If you add `DoEvents` to the beginning of your code, does that solve the issue?

Comment: `Alt` + `x` refers the add-ins tab. Why can't you just call the desired add-in macro by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification.

```
Dim dTILL as double
SendKeys ("%(xsr)"), True
dTill = Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2)
Do While dTILL>Now: DoEvents: Loop
```

That should get the message pump to allow outside processes to catch up.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.  Thank everyone else for your responses as well.