# Excel VBA - Range(..).Select doesn't work after Application.SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on some VBA code:

```vb
Sub Move(ByVal Sheet As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A1").Select 'THIS WORKS
    
    For i = 1 To 3
        Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    Next i
        
    For i = 1 To 3
        Application.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    Next i
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A1").Select 'THIS DOESN'T WORK    
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that the sent keys are working but this last line

```vb
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet).Range("A1").Select
```

does nothing. It's like it's ignored.

Any explanation?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it work for another cell like B1 ?

Comment: Don't use select function. Especially when there is no user involved and it's automation script!

Comment: It is working as expected: range `D4` is selected. What should in your opinion be the final selection's address?

Comment: `SendKeys` has a [second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement#syntax). You are not using it. Hence, your keystrokes are processed after your macro returns.

Comment: I added ", True" as second parameter but still the A1 isn't selected unless I force a pause using a dummy "MsgBox" but this is not what I want.

Comment: Throw in [a `DoEvents` or two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26304926/11683).